# shortest way to check, if constant defined and not empty

Tags: php

## EDIT:

THIS QUESTION hasnt' been already asked, so, before CLOSING, read it at first.

## question:

there are 3 possible variations:

```
define('my_constant',  'something');
// or
define('my_constant',  '');
// or
'my_constant' not defined at all
```

is there shortest way, rather than:

```
if (defined('my_constant') && my_constant!='')
```

p.s. `if(!empty(my_constant))`  throws error if not defined..

Comment: Have to disagree with the close-as-duplicate. This is not an "exact duplicate": this question asks how to combine checking whether the constant is defined (ie: the other question) with empty-checking, and specifically how to do so in the shortest way.

Comment: Since you specifically asked for the Shortest Way: ```if(!empty(@constant('MY_CONSTANT')) { ... }``` - the constant function will return either the value of the constant, or NULL if not defined. It will throw a warning in that case, though. Note that I'm not saying this is the Right Way (with the error-silencing and everything).

Comment: It is not a duplicate, in second one nobody is checking if constant is empty

Comment: @kander using quiet or as I like to call 'shut up' operator @ is a really bad practice.

Comment: Definitely a bad practice - like I said, it's not the right way. If I could still post an answer I'd have elaborated on that.

Comment: THIS **IS NOT DUPLICATE**, why you've closed ?!!!

Comment: what is a shortest way anyway? I can define a function `_` that will do the check that you do and is only 1 character long. Is this your definition of shortest?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!defined('MY_CONSTANT')) {
    die("constant is not defined");
}
if (empty(MY_CONSTANT)) {
    die("constant is defined, but empty");
}
```

OR

```
if (!defined('MY_CONSTANT') || empty(MY_CONSTANT)) {
    die("constant is not defined or empty");
}
```

Comment: User specifically asked for the *shortest way*, so have to disagree with this.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla use this all over the place:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

[Documentation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)